# Bootstrap Panel doesn't look right

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-grid

[Here's a plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/twYHS1tLO2JyPnf3DaHs?p=preview) I've been working on for another question. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but I see the bootstrap examples ([plunk](http://embed.plnkr.co/BoQi5vDIDivY1aqts1fW/)), and they look like this:

[image]

While mine looks like this (specifically look at the panel-headings / panel-titles):

[image]

My panel-heading has no styling at all, even though we're using practically the same code:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.3.2.js"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-header">
      <h4 class="panel-title" uib-tooltip="ok">ui-grid tester</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <button ng-click="changeColumn2Text()">Change Column 2 Text</button>
      <br />
      <br />
      <div class="grid" ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-selection=""></div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

The only difference is their panel is in a template (on the same page, with no special styles or classes) to use for an accordion, which doesn't seem to me like it should affect the styling.

So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `panel-header` with `panel-heading` class